# Using python to query data from ElasticSearch

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I'm using python's elasticsearch module to connect and search through my elasticsearch cluster. In the cluster, there's an index called gs_base and in the gs_base, there's something called "base_name" which stores all the company name that I want to extract. Can someone help me with the query code here? Thank you!

My code blow can only pull out everything in gs_base, but I need to list all company name in the field "base_name"

```
{
"_index": "gs_base",
"_type": "base",
"_id": "hgi-l2cB8nb3Ce91YtVS",
"_version": 1,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
...
"base_name":...
...
}

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import json


es = Elasticsearch(hosts="http://10.10.3.39:9200", http_auth=('xxx', 'xxx'))

query_json = {"query": {"bool": {"must": [], "must_not": [], "should": [{"match_all": {}}]}}, "from": 0, "size": 50, "sort": []}

query = es.search(index='gs_base',  body=query_json)
print(query)
```

I expect the result would be a list of company names stored in base_name

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_source`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) in query dsl to get only `base_name` field in the result. To do this update the `query_json` to below:

```
query_json = {"query":{"match_all":{}},"_source":["base_name"],"from":0,"size":50}
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way that I can just print the content in base_name line by line? The current output is: '_source': {'base_name': 'aaaaaaaa'}}, {'_index': 'gs_base', '_type': 'base', '_id': 'uwi-l2cB8nb3Ce91YtVT', '_score': 1.0, '_source': {'base_name': 'ccccccccccc'}}, {'_index': 'gs_base', '_type': 'base',      I wonder if the output could be like aaaaaaa, cccccccc, etc. So just the content itself, thanks

Comment: That is not possible as an elastic response. You need to handle this at application level.